# Date of valid weekday(0,1,2,...,6) as a value of textbox when i load page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

help please,
I have a textbox, and a number nday,

nday is the number of the day of week:

0 for sunday, 1 for monday,..., 6 for saturday

i want to make a code using javascript or jquery or php, to set the value of the textbox on load of the page equal to the first date of the current month,

example:

if nday=3, that means it's a wednesday, I want the date of the first wednesday of the current month to be the shown on the textbox, but i have to make sure that this date will not be < date of today

```html
<input type="text" name="d">
```

Comment: it can be 31-mar in one place and 1-apr in another, do you want the result based on the users time or your time?

Comment: on my time, for example, today we are on thursday==>4, i want, if nday=3 , that the value is 2017-04-12, the first valid wednesday  date

Comment: https://3v4l.org/joWAv @HasanHajjar Something like that? Will always get the next Wednesday. Not sure if I understand your requirement really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$nday = 3;
$today = date('d') + 1;
$total_month_days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date("m"), date("Y"));

$day = null;
for($i = $today; $i <= $total_month_days; $i++)
{
    $date = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), $i, date("Y"));
    $current_nday = date("w", $date);
    if($current_nday == $nday)
    {
        $day = $i;
        break;
    }
}

if(!empty($day)) echo date("Y")."-".date("m")."-".$day;
```

Comment: thanks it works :) i have edited the code a little bit, and it is totally working ,  thanks for your help bro <3

Answer (score 0):

The algo that I can think of is :

```
function find_date():
   if (value of n) < (today's day of the week):
     then say k = (today's day of week) - n
     so the date on the next nth day would be:
     answer = (today's date) + (7-k)
     // 7 because it is the total number of days in a week
   else if (value of n) > (today's day of the week):
     it would simply be
     answer = (today's date) + (value of n)
   else if (value of n) == (today's day of the week):
     answer = today's date
   return answer
```

So say for example n=3 (meaning Wednesday) and today being Thursday (that is day 4 of the week), so if we need to find out what would be the date on the next Wednesday, as per our algo above:

```
if n<3 (which is true in our example)
so k = 4 - 3 = 1
So date on next Wednesday would be:
(Today's date = 6th April 2017) + (7-1) 
which is equal to :

6th April + 6 = April 12th 2017
```

Now the code implementation of the above should not be too hard to figure out. (Not sure if there are any libraries that already do this):

Comment: what if for example today is wednesday? today has not been finished yet, so i wnat that the code returns the date of today